# How to modify the \question command in exam class

Tags: macros, hyperref, exam, bookmarks

I create math exams using `\documentclass[legalpaper, 12pt]{exam}` and `\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}`.

Each question is created by inserting `\question[points]` in the document and the enumeration of the questions is automatically created.

In order to see markers of each question in Texmaker, I use `\label{Q-number}` and in order to create bookmarks in the pdf for each question I use `\pdfbookmark[1]{Q-number}{Q-number}`.

So for example, for Question 4 which has 9 points I would write:

```
\label{Q4}
\pdfbookmark[1]{Q4}{Q4}
\question[9] Solve the equation $x+1=3$.
```

**Question 1:** Do you know how to create a macro like the one below?

```
\def\macroquestion #1{\label{Q-number}
    \pdfbookmark[1]{Q-number}{Q-number}
    \question[#1] }
```

so then I just have to write

```
\macroquestion{9} Solve the equation $x+1=3$.
```

where the counter Q-number gets automatically generated (depending only on the place where the command appears in the document).

Also, when a question has parts (3 and 4 points respectively) I usually type something like:

```
\question Solve the following equations:
\begin{parts}
\part[3] \label{Q4(a)}
\pdfbookmark[2]{Q4(a)}{Q4(a)} Solve the equation $x+1=3$.
\part[4] \label{Q4(b)}
\pdfbookmark[2]{Q4(b)}{Q4(b)} Solve the equation $x+9=8$.
\end{parts}
```

**Question 2:** Do you know how to create a `\macropart` that can take care of the counters Q4(a) and Q4(b), the labels and the bookmarks automatically similarly to `\macroquestion`?

Comment: Have you considered the `\newenvironment` construct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following definitions of `\newquestion` and `\newpart` seems to achieve what you're looking for. The difference between what you suggested (as `\macroquestion`) is that it still takes an *optional* argument and rearranges the setting of the `\question`, followed by the `\label` and `\pdfbookmark`. In your original setup there may have been a incorrect hypertarget set for the label or bookmark.

[image]

```
\documentclass{exam}

\usepackage[bookmarks]{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\newquestion}{ o }{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\question[#1]}
    {\question}%
  \label{Q\thequestion}%
  \pdfbookmark[1]{Q\thequestion}{Q\thequestion}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\newpart}{ o }{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}
    {\part[#1]}
    {\part}%
  \label{Q\thequestion(\thepartno)}%
  \pdfbookmark[2]{Q\thequestion(\thepartno)}{Q\thequestion(\thepartno)}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
  \newquestion[9] Solve the equation $x+1=3$.

  \newquestion Solve the following equations:
  \begin{parts}
    \newpart[3] Solve the equation $x+1=3$.
    \newpart[4] Solve the equation $x+9=8$.
  \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Werner! I just had to add \usepackage{xparse} and it worked smothly.

Comment: @Chilote: If that's the case then you need to consider updating your (La)TeX distribution. [`xparse`](//ctan.org/pkg/xparse)'s functionality has been add to the LaTeX kernel since Oct 2020. Adding `xparse` manually the way you did will suffice though.